# Is it possible to color a strikethrough line differ from the main text color in the .docx file via editing its data files?

Tags: xml, ms-word, openxml, docx, styling

Any `.docx` file is an archive with data files in it. The main content of the any `.docx` file is stored in the `word\document.xml` data file inside the `.docx` file. Strikethrough lines are represented as an `<w:strike/>` elements in this data file.

The URI of the `w` namespace is `http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main`

I would like to get in Word documents something like that:

```html
<span style='color:red;text-decoration:line-through'>
    <span style='color:blue;'>Blue text strikethrough with a red line</span>
</span>
```

So, maybe there is a way to edit properties of the `<w:strike/>` element, specify custom namespaces or something else.

In other words, please, tell me how can I change in `.docx` files the color of strikethrough lines only if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a different color for the strikethrough effect is not supported.

As specified in section 2.3.2.35 of part 4 of the Office Open XML specification, the `strike` element has a single attribute `val` of type `ST_OnOff`. This attribute only allows to switch the strikethrough effect on or off (similar with the `dstrike` element for double strikethrough).

If you need a different color, you would have to use a shape overlay. Unfortunately, there is no way to format the shape so that automatically extends with the text.

Comment: Please share a link to the specification.